# Select query with any two or n parameters

Tags: postgresql, select, any

My Postgres table holds details of places where people visit.  I am using a select query to select the locations.

```
SELECT maid,hlat,hlon,wlat,wlon FROM peopledata WHERE (  ( placecategory ILIKE '%Grocerypharmacydairy%' OR   placecategory ILIKE '%Marketarea%' OR   placecategory ILIKE '%Shoppingmall%'  ) OR( geobehavior ILIKE '%Grocerypharmacydairy_Visitor%' OR   geobehavior ILIKE '%Marketarea_Visitor%' OR   geobehavior ILIKE '%Shoppingmall_Visitor%'  ) OR( gender ILIKE '%both%' ) AND( age between '25' and '60'  )) AND polygonid IN (2333)
```

In the above query, I have three `placecategory` and 3 `geobehavior` parameters.  Through a different input, I am also capturing details of how many placecategory or geobehavior should be matched.  For example,

```
placecategory : 2
geobehavior : 3
```

If the n value for placecategory is 2, I want to select records matching 'any' two of these parameters.  For example, it could be

```
Grocerypharmacydairy AND Marketarea  OR
Grocerypharmacydairy AND Shoppingmall OR
Marketarea AND Shoppingmall
```

Depending on the number of locations specified, I want to fetch the records that match at least the n-parameters specified.

Comment: As I understand your `placecategory` is actually not a single category but a list of several categories in a single text field. Why not have it text[]? Are you free to change the type of `placecategory`?

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis The placecategory is already a text field in the table.  For each Id in the table, the placecategory column in the table has values like `"ShoppingMall, SuperMarket, Pharmacy, Bar'` I am trying to search for any one who match with `n` category through the select query.

Answer (score 0):

So the question boils down to "how to find an intersection of 2 sets of text" (and find the rank of it).

First we have to extract categories from the `placecategory` field. For the sake of example lets say it contains "ShoppingMall, SuperMarket, Pharmacy, Bar". PostgreSQL 8.3+ has [regexp_split_to_table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) for that.

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table('ShoppingMall, SuperMarket, Pharmacy, Bar', ', ') as category
```

Returns:

```
category    |
------------+
ShoppingMall|
SuperMarket |
Pharmacy    |
Bar         |
```

Now lets assume you want to get the intersection with "Pharmacy, Bar, Barberry"

```
SELECT 
  count(*) as intersection_rank
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT 
     regexp_split_to_table(
       'ShoppingMall, SuperMarket, Pharmacy, Bar', 
       ', ') as val ) as category_from_peopledata
  JOIN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT 
     regexp_split_to_table(
       'Pharmacy, Bar, Barberry', 
       ', ') as val) as required_categories ON category_from_peopledata.val = required_categories.val
```

The intersection is  "Pharmacy, Bar" so the result is as expected:

```
intersection_rank|
-----------------+
                2|
```

I use DISTINCT to guard against the duplicates in `categories` or the `required_categories`. If you ensure the categories does not have duplicates in the list - you may remove DISTINCT.

You may now use the query in WHERE clause to check the number of categories that matches and filter the `peopledata` table.

The same principle goes for the `geobehavior` attribute.

**CAUTION**

Just be aware, that if you expect the `peopledata` table to grow big, you will face performance issues. Searching for the records with "Bar" in `placecategory` will  be performed using seqscan.